# How to remove #region in visual studio along with all its content

Tags: visual-studio, csla, codesmith

I Used Codesmith to generate CSLA Template.
But Codesmith generates Asynchronous Factory Methods Which I dont want and which are full of
'Csla.DataPortal' does not contain a definition for 'CreateAsync'... errors.

So I want to remove all the code inside the region "#region Asynchronous Factory Methods" in the BL project or at least be able to fix the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that DataPortal.CreateAsync was part of CSLA Version 4.5.

I updated the reference and my problem was solved!